# How to Apply a Texture to an Orthographic Plane Using DirectX11 Shaders

Tags: c++, textures, shader, hlsl, directx-11

I'm currently trying to apply a texture image to an orthographic plane so that it can be used as a kind of 'U.I. decoration'.

The plane is made up of two tri's in a D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP format. When I attempt to render the plane with the shader, it just comes out as white (or invisible if I have blend state set to true). I believe that it's because I am only sampling the four corners of the texture on the orthographic plane as I'm only sampling in the vertex shader.

This is the current code in my shaders:

```
void VSMain( const VSInput input, out PSInput output) {
    output.pos = input.pos;
    output.pos = mul( output.pos, g_WVP);

    float2 tex_pos;
    float4 Tex;
    tex_pos.x = ( input.pos.x + 512) / 1024;
    tex_pos.y = (-input.pos.z + 512) / 1024;

    Tex = g_materialMap.SampleLevel( g_sampler, tex_pos, 0);

    output.colour = Tex;
}

void PSMain( const PSInput input, out PSOutput output) {
    output.colour = input.colour;
}
```

When I apply this shader to the heightmap that I'm currently rendering in the scene, it works properly, however it doesn't work properly on the orthographic plane.

Can anyone help me apply this texture to the orthographic plane correctly? (If required, I can provide screenshots of the current scene)

Comment: Can you provide your creation of the vertices and your drawing code? A screenshot would be interesting too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered and fixed the problem myself.

The sampling DOES need to be done in the pixel shader for it to colour correctly, but I missed out adding the texture to being visible to the pixel shader.

The fix is as follows:

switch the line

```
Tex = g_materialMap.SampleLevel( g_sampler, tex_pos, 0);
```

to

```
output.tex = tex_pos;
```

Then, in the pixel shader just put

```
float4 Tex = g_materialMap.Sample( g_sampler, input.tex);
output.colour = Tex;
```